# Why can't I create new module on Android Studio 1.3 Preview 2?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I think the window is too large too be out of my Windows Frament,but i don't know how to fix it?who can give me some advice?

Comment: Does double clicking not work?  Maybe if you drag the window to the top of your screen it will fit to full screen

Comment: Hitting enter seems to work for me

Answer (score 3):

Although this is getting some downvotes it's actually kind of a valid question having just upgraded it myself to see what OP is talking about.  The dialog gives you no way to resize it, and the next button is at the bottom, and is easily cut off on a lower resolution monitor.  The easiest work around I see if to select the option you want then **press the enter key**, as nothing seems to be able to resize the window and double clicking doesn't work.  At each stage of the wizard enter always appears to continue it on, and most of the relevant things to fill out should be in view.

That window definitely has some bugs, it seems to let you resize it bigger but never smaller, and when you try to make it wider I just had it bug out and cut off the buttons on my 1080p monitor.  I'm guessing it's just a mess up on google's side, I'm sure they will fix it in a later release.  That's the price you pay getting builds from the dev channel =).

Comment: Your answer works. But I had to go through comments to Know answer. Do us a favour, Bold "Press Enter" in your answer .